# How can I get the similar attribute with xpath?

Tags: xpath, scrapy, elementtree

```
<div><a src="What I need" data-src="What I don't need">Demo</a></div>
```

I am tried this `xpath("./div/a/@src")`,but it will give me all of that, but I don't want the `@data-src`, how should  I do???

the raw page is here:

[the raw page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMr8p.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

first of all I would recommend you to change the `@src-data` in `data-src`!
it will avoid you many problems when parsing XML files.

Then you can use directly the following **XPATH** to get your src attribute:

```
/div/a/@src
```

if you make it start with . it will only access the relative path from the current node.

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake , the "What I don't need " the attribute is @data-src, so when I use xpath('./div/a/@src'), i can get all of that, and thanks for u answer, how should I do?

Comment: You should remove the @ from your attribute in the tag definition, if you do not do it you will have a malformed xml file and your XPATH will not return what it should... `<div><a src="What I need" data-src="What I don't need">Demo</a></div>`

Comment: oh My!you are all right.this is the crawl project.I just use `xpath('./div/a/@src')`to get the "what I need",but I get the all of the attribute,I don't know how could I limit the attribute?